# Nginx redirect all requests trying to reach a folder

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

How can I redirect all requests trying to reach a folder?

for example, I would like to redirect:

```
somedomain.com/folder/subfolder/index.html
somedomain.com/folder/subfolder2/something.html
somedomain.com/folder/subfolder3/somethingelse.html
```

to

```
somedomain2.com/index.html
```

what I've tried:

```
if ( $request_uri = "/folder/.*" ) {
  rewrite ^/(.*)$  http://domain2.com/embed.html    permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're just complicating things for no reason, no need to do an if condition, you should always try to [avoid it as much as possible](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil)

```
location /folder { # this will match all subfolders and files
    return 301 http://domain2.com/embed.html;
}
```